# Проблема с NullReferenceExeption

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть такой кусочек кода. При входе в триггер выдает NullRefExe. Не понимаю, на что ему ссылку нужно дать. Весь текст ошибки:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
> object PreparationToFight.Landing () (at Assets/My
> Assets/Script/Enemy/PreparationToFight.cs:15)
> PreparationToFight.OnTriggerEnter (UnityEngine.Collider other) (at
> Assets/My Assets/Script/Enemy/PreparationToFight.cs:22)

```
public void Landing()
{

    _player.PlayerObj.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(_player.PlayerObj.transform.position, _platform.transform.position, _landingSpeed);
}

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        Landing();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну у вас либо `_player` null, либо `PlayerObj`, т.к. по стэку указывает на ту строку

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/729628)

Comment: @Spatz ошибаешься